# What are the pitfalls of this utility function to map over a mutable reference?

Tags: rust

I sometimes find myself wanting to transform a value behind a mutable reference, but it's not possible in the naive/simple way. I can implement this in the more complex way below, but I assume that the stdlib has some good reason for not providing this type of functionality. Probably it can break in some hideous ways. What are the dangers here? Is it only about the possibility for `f` to panic?

(Note that in my intended uses, `f` is a pure, infallible function, but of course the compiler/stdlib can't rely on that).

```
pub unsafe fn map_mut_ref<T>(
    x: &mut T,
    f: impl FnOnce(T) -> T,
) {
    // This is the simple version of what I want, but it doesn't compile.
    // *x = f(*x);

    let x2 = core::ptr::read(x);
    let x3 = f(x2);
    core::ptr::write(x, x3);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=55891467080f5a47156f5dba283ee0c4

Comment: Even if you think it's infallible, then note that if `f(x2)` were to panic, then `x2` (i.e. `x`) is dropped (thus dropped twice). Otherwise, your implementation is effectively the same as [`std::mem::replace()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) where `src` is a `FnMut(T) -> T` instead of `T`. Which there was an RFC proposal for years ago [`std::mem::replace_with()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1736)

Answer (score 2):

As you alluded to in your question, panic safety (or rather, the lack thereof) is the big issue with this code.

If panics are configured to [unwind the stack](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/unwinding.html) (which is the default behaviour in Rust), this code can trigger undefined behaviour, as if `f` panics, the runtime will try to drop the data before you've put it back where it belongs.

This can be confirmed via [Miri](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri) with [some fairly simple code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fa2dd56f4c29e6081219dce314a41e8):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo = String::from("foo");
    
    unsafe {
        map_mut_ref(&mut foo, |f| { panic!() });
    }
}
```

```rust
error: Undefined Behavior: out-of-bounds pointer use: alloc1460 has been freed, so this pointer is dangling
   --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:515:1
    |
515 | pub unsafe fn drop_in_place<T: ?Sized>(to_drop: *mut T) {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ out-of-bounds pointer use: alloc1460 has been freed, so this pointer is dangling
    |
    = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
    = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information
help: alloc1460 was allocated here:
   --> src/main.rs:14:19
    |
14  |     let mut foo = String::from("foo");
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: alloc1460 was deallocated here:
   --> src/main.rs:17:46
    |
17  |         map_mut_ref(&mut foo, |_| { panic!() });
    |                                              ^
    = note: BACKTRACE (of the first span):
    = note: inside `std::ptr::drop_in_place::<[u8]> - shim(None)` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:515:1: 515:56
    = note: inside `<std::vec::Vec<u8> as std::ops::Drop>::drop` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:3205:13: 3205:91
    = note: inside `std::ptr::drop_in_place::<std::vec::Vec<u8>> - shim(Some(std::vec::Vec<u8>))` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:515:1: 515:56
    = note: inside `std::ptr::drop_in_place::<std::string::String> - shim(Some(std::string::String))` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:515:1: 515:56
note: inside `main`
   --> src/main.rs:19:1
    |
19  | }
    | ^
```

`map_mut_ref` is an `unsafe` function, so it would be a valid solution to simply document the invariant that `f` must be a non-panicking closure. However, this feels a bit risky to me, as there is a lot of seemingly-innocuous code in Rust that can panic (bounds checks, overflows, etc).

The best option would be to avoid writing code that needs to take a `T` out of a `&mut T` - but if you can't, the next best thing would be to use the [`take_mut`](https://docs.rs/take_mut/latest/take_mut/) crate, which implements the same thing as your code, but in several ways that handle panics more gracefully (either by aborting the process, or by replacing the data with a default value).

As a bonus, this means their implementation can be used in safe code.